# Redirection loop URL rewriting

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect, friendly-url

I'm redirecting all my .php extensions to .html, but I'm getting a loop problem.

For example, from:

```
-mywebsite.com/country/france-php/paris.php
```

to

```
-mywebsite.com/country/france-php/paris.html
```

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    
RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ $1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ $1.php [L] 
FallbackResource /index.php
```

When analyzing with redirection detective I get many redirections to:

```
-mywebsite.com/country/france-php/paris.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the first redirection based on raw request received:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1.php [L]
```

---

To load `index.php` as `index.html` too, you can add the following rewrite at the top:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1/index.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: works fine for : -mywebsite.com/country/france-php/paris.php and -mywebsite.com/country/france-fcret/ but not for -mywebsite.com/country/france-php/

Comment: @IssamHmz What should happen for `mywebsite.com/country/france-php/`?

Comment: inside france-php file an index.php so it must open it, but with your solution it doesn't open it    only files as france-xrf france -fff are opened

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)\.php([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ %1.html%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{DOUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRUle ^(.+)\.html(?:(/.*)|)$ $1.php$2 [L]
```

The problem is that the rewrite engine loops and your two rules keep overwriting each other. By adding some conditions, you can prevent that.

Comment: works fine for : -mywebsite.com/country/france-php/paris.php     and    -mywebsite.com/country/france-fcret/   but not  for -mywebsite.com/country/france-php/

Answer (score 0):

You can try your rules this way.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ %1.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: works fine for : -mywebsite.com/country/france-php/paris.php and -mywebsite.com/country/france-fcret/ but not for -mywebsite.com/country/france-php/